# React native variable declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whats the difference between these way of declaring variables in react-native.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
export default class Hello extends Component {
render() {
**const var1 = 'hi';**
return ( );
}}

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
**const var1 = 'hi';**
export default class Hello extends Component {
render() {
return ( );
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you know what a scope of a variable is?

Comment: @acdcjunior yes I do, my question is more specific to react native. Would you be able to answer ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between those variables is **scope**.

In both cases, [due to the use of **`const`**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations), `var1` will only be accessible ***after*** its declaration.

The scope of a `const` variable is it's running [**execution context**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts). In your two examples, the execution contexts are different.

In the second example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
const var1 = 'hi';
export default class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( );
  }
}
```

The *execution context* where `var1` is declared is the **file**.

This means that **at any point in the file** after `const var1 = 'hi';` **the `var1` variable is available** and its value is `'hi'`.

In your first example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
export default class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    const var1 = 'hi';
    return ( );
  }
}
```

The *execution context* of the declaration is the method `render()`.

Similarly, it means that at any point **in the `render()` method and *ONLY* inside that `render()` method** after the `const var1 = 'hi';` statement the `var1` variable is available and its value will be `'hi'`.

## tl;dr

In summary, when you use `const var1 = 'hi';` inside a method, the `var1` (constant) variable will **only** be available **inside** that method. OTOH, when you declare `const var1 = 'hi';` in the file, outside of any class or `{}` or function, `var1` will be available in the whole file.

In both cases, though, `var1` will only be defined/available after the `const var1 = 'hi';` declaration statement.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation, really appreciate it, exactly what I was looking for.. will it make any performance difference defining the variables in file scope vs method scope?

Comment: In general, you'll want to keep the scope of your variables as "focused" as possible. This is more a maintainability measure than a performance one.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. appreciate it 

Comment: As far as performance goes, doesn't make any difference if you declare a variable in one or another scope. The variable will be "allocated" as long as that scope is in execution.

Comment: So if you have a variable declared inside a method, it will allocate memory every time that method runs (but will stay allocated just when that method is running). If you declare in a file, it will be available until any code (a class, a function) of that file exists and uses it (there's less allocate-deallocate, but otoh they will stay longer in memory while being not used). As you can see, there are advantages and drawbacks for both.

Comment: In general, though, a single variable is very unlikely to affect your apps performance. You shouldn't worry about it. (You will know when you should, it will be very obvious, like opening a spreadsheet of a million rows.) As said, we prefer to keep scopes small/focused because it is easier to understand and maintain code. When a variable has a wide scope (like in your second/file example), there's too much code that can access it (or change it when it is not a `const`), so a future programmer may have a harder time trying to fully grasp really why that variable is useful.

Comment: And, just as final note, this behavior is not specific to react-nactive, it is the same in all environments of javascript. (The small scope guideline is actually for **all** languages.) But that's it! Cheers! :D